# User feedback data presentation

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using GA to track users feedback on a per page level, "Did you find this page usefull? 'yes':'no'" i ask the users

using these GA calls:

```
yes: 
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'User Feedback', 'Yes', 3]);

no: 
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'User Feedback', 'No', 3]);
```

Now i want to display the result per page level in a custom report, but i can't manage to figure out how to configure the report. How do i present this boolean data in a report, when data can either be "yes" or "no"?

I appreciate any help you could provide. Thanks!

EDIT:

My report so long looks like this:

```
metric: 
-unique events

dimension:
- Page
   - [my custom variable value]
```

Nothing more.

This will result in a report that shows correct result at page level, meaning i need klick on each specifik page to get the yes:no rate. If I'm not in page level but the overview view, I get this chart showing the percent of all pages based on total votes, not what I want as you can guess. Sorry, cant post pic.

So, what do i need to do to get the yes:no rate for each page on the overview level/view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find it in the Dimension Drilldowns.

Custom Events seem more appropriate for what you're trying to do here, though.

Comment: Ok. Using Custom events may fit better.